# Ignores URLSession.shared.dataTask

Tags: ios, swift

I've created an API call which are going to retrieve weather, but somehow my URLSession is never executed.

```
downloadJsonData(urlString: urlString) {
    print("completed")
}
```

I'm calling the method from a button click.

```
func downloadJsonData(urlString: String, completed: @escaping () -> ()){

    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {return}

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
        guard let data = data else{
            return
        }

        do{
            self.dataArray.append(try JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseData.self, from: data))

            //Complete task in background
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completed()
            }
        }
        catch let jsonErr{
            print(jsonErr)
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

And the app never prints "completed". (I'm using the exact same code on another viewcontroller and that works perfectly fine....)

When I debug and clicks on "Jump-into" the app goes to the function, and reads the "guard let url=" but then jumps to the "}" at the very bottom, and then re-directs back to the button where the function is called.

Comment: What do you see if you `print(string)` before `return` when the guard fails?

Comment: @PhillipMills Should I add the print above "guard let url = URL"?

Comment: @PhillipMills I'm getting the correct UrlString when I'm printing. But once I entered the function I got:

`2020-02-20 20:52:55.911414+0100 weatherAppLabb1[22199:1955702] XPC connection interrupted`

Comment: My thought was to change `else {return}` so that there was a print before return.

Comment: @PhillipMills I did, and it failed. I fixed that issue and now it's finally going through. But found something else on the way. hold on